# Is the maximum entropy distribution the same for conditional and unconditional moments?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, moments, maximum-entropy

Suppose I have a set of observations drawn from some finite interval from a distribution that has a range that includes that interval but extends beyond it. This could be either because of the values outside the range are censored (in which case we may know how many observations there are outside the range, but not their values) or intrinsic to the data-generating process, as when you know that a detector is only able to pick up values if they fall in a specified range.

From these observations, I have a set of moments, with the highest moment even.

If the range were the real line (or the positive half-line? I think so) this would suffice to specify a maximum entropy distribution. But suppose the moments from the observations on that interval are all I have. I believe this should still be sufficient to specify a maximum entropy distribution.  My question is, if you have the same set of moments, only conditional on the observations being in the specified interval, is the maximum entropy distribution the same as if you had the unconditional moments?

I know you would have to use a different estimation procedure if you want to recover the correct parameters. But would they be parameters of the same distribution in the two cases?